# How do I calculate the number of times angle X should be added to obtain angle Y?

Tags: geometry, modular-arithmetic

Suppose I have a `angle X=100` and `angle Y=60`.
when we add `X` 15 times it gives `Y`.
How do I calculate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You want to solve $100x\equiv 60\pmod{360}$. We are using the fact that two angles are *coterminal* if they differ by an integer multiple of $360^\circ$.

Equivalently (divide through by $20$) you want to solve $5x\equiv 3\pmod{18}$.

Comment: Does that mean I need to get modular multiplicative inverse of 60,360?

Comment: Multiplicative inverse doesn't work for $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ if $a$ and $m$ are not relatively prime. That's why I divided through by $20$, the gcd of $100$ and $360$. Once we are at $5x\equiv 3\pmod{18}$, we can multiply through by the inverse of $5$ modulo $18$ to find $x$. Or else, since $18$ is a pretty small number, we can find $x$ by "trial and error."