# How to solve equations with modulus in them

Tags: arithmetic

For e.g.

(100 * X) % 35 = 25

gives X = 2

and on similar note

(100 * X) % 360 = 80

gives X = 8

and it can be possible that there is no X which satisfy this

for e.g.

(100 * X) % 360 = 70

there is no X possible in above case

Comment: Are you familiar with congruences, i.e $\, a\equiv b\pmod m\iff m\,$ divides $\,a-b,\,$ and their arithmetic? Do you know Bezout's Identity for the gcd, or Fermat's little Theorem? Please give some background or context so that we can answer at the appropriate level.

Comment: @BillDubuque doesn't look he is familiar with modular arithmetic,otherwise that notation would have been used. Is my answer complete? Anything you'd like to add?

Comment: @amitchhajer you should have asked AndreNicolas. He answered your question, he would have been happy to provide more details. Anyway, is my answer clear to you?

Comment: who is AndreNicolas?

Comment: @amitchhajer my bad. I thought this was your question. Apparently not. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713406/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-times-angle-x-should-be-added-to-obtain-angle-y

Comment: same numbers. weird.

Comment: @amitchhajer Please say a litle about how much number theory you know, e.g. the congruence form of your first equation is $\ 100 x\equiv 60 \pmod{360}.\,$ Are you familiar with such congruences and their arithmetic?

Comment: Not really Bill. But I can understand what Sabyasachi has given answer as. Not too good in mathematics. Where should I read more about this?

Comment: @amitchhajer Unfortunately the accepted answer is incorrect, and contains various misunderstandings. I don't think that an MSE answer is the best place to attempt to learn congruence arithmetic. Any textbook on elementary number theory will cover this. I recommend browsing the shelves/pages at your local/virtual library to find a textbook that matches your level of knowledge. While you could learn much from prior answers here, but that would be much less efficient than using a good textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Using C notation `(a*X) % n = b`, such a $X$ exists if and only if the GCD (greatest common divisor) of $a$ and $n$ is a divisor of $b$ (of course, assuming $0 \le b < n$). I am afraid that the method to actually find a solution uses more tools than you are familiar with, but at least you can easily check whether a solution exists, and if so you can always do an exhaustive search, which should be fine in your setting. (If you want to know more, a Google search for "linear congruence" yields plenty of references, but you might have to get familiar with congruences first.)